# Class-A power amplifier magnitude and phase

Tags: analog, bjt, simulation, multisim, power-amplifier

I just did a simulation in Multisim of a class-A power amplifier, but the phase graph of the AC sweep (AC analysis) is not what I expected.

With the reference circuit diagram, I simulated the circuit in Multisim 14.3, and got the AC analysis. Then when I compared it with the sample AC analysis, the magnitude had a similar half circle dome shape, although my result is flatter. Then I compared the phase; the sample is going down then sudden increases, then goes down again, whereas in my simulation, the phase is just going down.

I also searched and watched a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=By2d-sa4ybs) titled *Simulation of Class A Power Amplifier Using Multisim*. In the video the circuit is similar, just different values of the RC components and the AC voltage. The AC analysis also had a half-dome shaped magnitude and the phase is similar to the sample AC analysis with a sudden increase in the middle.

I don't know much about power amplifiers, just the AC-DC load line, quiescent power, etc. I don't know anything about the sudden change in phase and the magnitude values. Can someone try to explain about the varying results and the theory behind these?

Reference circuit diagram:
[image: Reference circuit diagram]

My simulated class-A amplifier in Multisim:
[image: My simulated Class A amplifier in Multisim]

Sample simulation AC analysis:
[image: Sample simulation AC analysis]

My AC analysis of the class-A amplifier in Multisim:
[image: My AC analysis of the Class A amplifier in Multisim]

YouTube simulation of class-A amplifier in Multisim:
[image: YouTube simulation of Class A amplifier in Multisim]

YouTube simulation AC analysis:
[image: YouTube simulation AC analysis]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *then to compare the phase, the sample is going down then sudden
> increase, then going down again, whereas in my simulation, the phase
> is just going down.*

The graph jumps from -180° to +180° and although this looks like a discontinuity it isn't. Think about it for a while: -

[image]

Comment: So the jump from -180° to +180° has a phase difference of 360° which means the phase change has gone through a complete 360° phase change, so the -180° to +180°, and its now continuing a new cycle is actually the same as my own AC analysis simulation where the phase is decreasing the whole time?

Comment: I still have no clue what is going on, and why is my ac analysis not having the -180° to +180° phase shift, it is the simulation setup wrong?

Comment: If you set the upper and lower phase limits in the plot correctly, the graph will be continuous.

Comment: I get what you mean now, but I can't seem to set the phase axis it just doesn't show what the values beyond the axis. Thank you!

Comment: I don't use multisim so I can't advise about that but, I suspect there should be a way to do this @randomnick